# Compare columns of two dataframes and filter dataframe based on the condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The two dataframes are as shown

`Name  Score 
 John  0.27
 Peter 0.34
 David 0.89
 Sarah 0.67
 Tom   0.93`

`Name  minScore
 John  0.50
 Peter 0.20
 David 0.90
 Sarah 0.50
 Tom   0.90`

I want to compare the column(Score) of first dataframe with column(minScore) of the second dataframe and get a filtered first dataframe 
`df = dataframe1['score']>dataframe2['minscore']`

final ouput is as shown

`Name  Score
 Peter 0.34
 Sarah 0.67
 Tom   0.93`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join dataframes on field *Name*

```
df = dataframe1.merge(dataframe2, on='Name')
```

and filter result:

```
df[df.Score > df.minScore]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a series indexed with `Name` and use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) in constructing your Boolean condition. I also recommend you [`copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) explicitly if you wish to guarantee you aren't left with a view.

```
min_map = df2.set_index('Name')['minScore']
df = df1.loc[df1['Score'] > df1['Name'].map(min_map)].copy()
```